# I have a problem with making asterisk pyramid with python

Tags: python

Question is from [here](https://level.goorm.io/exam/43328/%ED%94%BC%EB%9D%BC%EB%AF%B8%EB%93%9C/quiz/1). It's written in Korean.

This is a problem of making a pyramid of N layers using the input N.
The range of N must be bigger than 0 and smaller than 100 
If the N is out of the range, the program should print "?"

'입력' means input. 
'출력' means output.

I think my code doesn't have a problem showing the pyramid i want, but there is a case that i can't pass and i don't know what that is.

```py
UserInput = int(input())

if UserInput > 0 and UserInput < 100:
    for i in range(1, UserInput + 1):
        print(" " * (UserInput-i) + "*" * (2 * i - 1))

else:
    print("?")
```

I don't know where is a problem in my code. 
The site which provide this question says that there is some case that couldn't pass. 
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also output the trailing spaces.

This code works:

```
UserInput = int(input())

if UserInput > 0 and UserInput < 100:
    for i in range(1, UserInput + 1):
        print(" " * (UserInput-i) + "*" * (2 * i - 1) + " " * (UserInput-i))

else:
    print("?")
```

Comment: surprising! thx. but i wonder what the difference is.. could you tell me why?

Comment: When you look at example 3 at the link, the first line to output is:
[space]*[space]
I replaced the symbol they use with [space], this stands for a space-character.
This means the task requires you to also output the spaces after the *

Your code only output: 
[space]*